# Spell check turned off in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, openoffice, spell-check

I have an Acer Aspire "E15 Start" laptop running Windows 8.1.  Recently, it seems that somehow the spell check feature on all applications and websites has been "globally" turned off.

No misspelled words are highlighted inside Facebook, Messenger, Stack Exchange, OpenOffice Writer, nothing.  Running a "manual" spell check inside Writer causes the spell check to complete with nothing found, even on a document containing obviously misspelled words.  Adjusting the settings on Office has no results.

I've looked at the following settings page: [Windows Spell Check Settings](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-spell-checker-auto-correct-windows)
and both "highlight misspelled words" and "autocorrect" are checked to "on."

What could be happening?

Comment: At any point did you disable this feature by changing the name of the filesi in question?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't believe so.  Which files would those be?

Comment: The page you linked to lists them

Comment: @Ramhound oh I must have missed that.  I will take a look.